# orderByChild() equalTo() returns null value in some cases

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

**Update at the bottom.**
I have a data structure like this:

```
"users" : {
  "-KXc0PDja_SUJndi9_Zt" : {
    "email" : "asd@gmail.com",
    "imageUri" : "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn....jpg",
    "name" : "John Doe",
    "uid" : "FtJyW7OdZBYSvrFCPMBqNkeXup32"
  },
  "-Kh3Agg9n0HnfKH7r1v6" : {
    "email" : "asd2@gmail.com",
    "imageUri" : "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/...photo.jpg",
    "name" : "John Doe",
    "uid" : "1H9EukKqzsazD6AQ10yEwS9ETHH3"
  }
}
```

I'm trying to determine, whether the user's data is already stored in my database, by trying to fetch the data, that has the stored *uid* equal to the user's **uid**. So from the *users* node I want to get the child that has the same *uid*, as the one passed to the *equalTo()* method. The following code is supposed to do this:

```
firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
                if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Toast.makeText(activity, "Signing task not successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    final FirebaseUser firebaseUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                    final String uid = firebaseUser.getUid();
                    if (firebaseUser != null) {
                        usersRef.orderByChild(FirebaseConstants.CHILD_USERS_UID/*value: uid*/).equalTo(uid).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(
                                new ValueEventListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                        if (!dataSnapshot.hasChildren()) { /*already tried dataSnapshot.getValue() == null*/
                                            /*In the cases explained in the description, this value is always null, even though the user with this exact uid already exists in the "users" node*/
                                            // create new entry in DB for this user
                                            final UserPojo userPojo =
                                                    new UserPojo(uid, firebaseUser.getDisplayName(),
                                                            firebaseUser.getPhotoUrl().toString(), firebaseUser.getEmail());
                                            final DatabaseReference usersBlankRef = usersRef.push();
                                            final String key = usersBlankRef.getKey();
                                            usersBlankRef.setValue(userPojo, (databaseError, databaseReference) -> {
                                                if (databaseError == null) {
                                                    final User user = User.fromPojo(userPojo);
                                                    user.setKey(key);
                                                    singleSubscriber.onSuccess(user);
                                                } else {
                                                    singleSubscriber.onError(new Throwable(databaseError.getDetails()));
                                                }
                                            });
                                        } else {
                                            // There should be only one user with the same UID.
                                            final DataSnapshot childSnapshot = dataSnapshot.getChildren().iterator().next();
                                            final UserPojo userPojo = childSnapshot.getValue(UserPojo.class);
                                            final User user = User.fromPojo(userPojo);
                                            user.setKey(childSnapshot.getKey());
                                            singleSubscriber.onSuccess(user);
                                        }
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                                        singleSubscriber.onError(new Throwable(databaseError.getDetails()));
                                    }
                                });
                    }
                }
            })
```

I also added the following rule (after having checked the Logcat logs I found a warning there regarding the missing .indexOn for users uid)

```
{  
    "rules": {
        ".read": "auth != null",
        ".write": "auth != null",

        "users": {
            ".indexOn": ["uid"] 
        }
    }
}
```

**The problem** is that while I'm running the android app on one device (user asd@gmail.com) the query returns proper data (it finds the user with the given uid. But when I try it on another device (account asd2@gmail.com) it doesn't - the dataSnapshot.getValue() is always null and the code keeps adding to the DB the same user (the same uid) over and over again. The uid value is actually the same, when I print it out.
What am I doing wrong?

**Update**
I observed that removing the following line fixed the issue:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
```

But I don't really understand how this works then, especially that both devices were online all the time.